# NULL Exception in my android program

Tags: android, crash

i have a crash:

```
03-16 17:47:57.058: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(609): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-16 17:47:57.058: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(609): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to      destroy activity {com.TravelPharmacy/com.TravelPharmacy.CountryView}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-16 17:47:57.058: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(609):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:2636)
03-16 17:47:57.058: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(609):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:2654)
03-16 17:47:57.058: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(609):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:117)
03-16 17:47:57.058: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(609):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:961)
03-16 17:47:57.058: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(609):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-16 17:47:57.058: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(609):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-16 17:47:57.058: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(609):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3647)
03-16 17:47:57.058: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(609):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-16 17:47:57.058: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(609):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-16 17:47:57.058: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(609):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
03-16 17:47:57.058: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(609):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
03-16 17:47:57.058: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(609):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-16 17:47:57.058: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(609): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-16 17:47:57.058: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(609):     at com.TravelPharmacy.CountryView.onDestroy(CountryView.java:117)
03-16 17:47:57.058: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(609):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:2623)
03-16 17:47:57.058: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(609): 
    ... 11 more
```

That is the onCreate of First activity, when you press on the button (fromButton) that will call the other activity and expect to get back the name of the country

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
    setContentView(R.layout.home);

   // final int recquestCode = 0;
    final Button btnCountryfrom = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fromButton);
    btnCountryfrom.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {

        public void onClick(View v)
        {


            Intent pingIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),CountryView.class);
            pingIntent.putExtra("btnText", " ");
            pingIntent.setClass(TravelPharmacy.this, CountryView.class);
            startActivityForResult(pingIntent, RECEIVE_MESSAGE);
            Log.i("tag for easy filter in logcat 6","I am Working!!!");
            ButtonFromPressed=true;

         }



    }); 
}
```

when getting back the name of the country that be choose in the other activity Override 
onActivityResult and set the name of country in the button

```
     @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

     Button btnCountryfrom = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fromButton);


        CharSequence seq = data.getCharSequenceExtra("response");
        btnCountryfrom.setText(seq);
        ButtonFromPressed=false;



    }
}
```

the onCreate of my second Activity

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.country);

    mListUsers = getCountry();
    lvUsers = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.countrylistView);
    lvUsers.setAdapter(new ListAdapter(this, R.id.countrylistView, mListUsers)); 



    lvUsers.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id)
        {



            Intent pongIntent = new Intent();

            Log.i("tag for easy filter in logcat 1", "information you provide");

            Log.i("tag for easy filter in logcat 2",mListUsers.get(position).pays);

            pongIntent.putExtra("response",mListUsers.get(position).pays);
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,pongIntent);

            finish();
            Log.i("tag for easy filter in logcat 3",mListUsers.get(position).pays);



        }
     });

}
```

i will appreciate help!!!

thanks!