# Getting a NullException

Tags: android, crash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [NULL Exception in my android program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325553/null-exception-in-my-android-program)

Have an Exception:

```
03-16 17:47:57.058: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(609): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-16 17:47:57.058: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(609): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to      destroy activity {com.TravelPharmacy/com.TravelPharmacy.CountryView}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-16 17:47:57.058: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(609):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:2636)
03-16 17:47:57.058: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(609):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:2654)
03-16 17:47:57.058: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(609):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:117)
03-16 17:47:57.058: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(609):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:961)
03-16 17:47:57.058: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(609):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-16 17:47:57.058: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(609):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-16 17:47:57.058: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(609):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3647)
03-16 17:47:57.058: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(609):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-16 17:47:57.058: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(609):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-16 17:47:57.058: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(609):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
03-16 17:47:57.058: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(609):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
03-16 17:47:57.058: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(609):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-16 17:47:57.058: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(609): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-16 17:47:57.058: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(609):     at com.TravelPharmacy.CountryView.onDestroy(CountryView.java:117)
03-16 17:47:57.058: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(609):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:2623)
03-16 17:47:57.058: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(609): 
    ... 11 more
```

That is the onCreate of First activity, when you press on the button (fromButton) that will call the other activity and expect to get back the name of the country

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
    setContentView(R.layout.home);

   // final int recquestCode = 0;
    final Button btnCountryfrom = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fromButton);
    btnCountryfrom.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {

        public void onClick(View v)
        {


            Intent pingIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),CountryView.class);
            pingIntent.putExtra("btnText", " ");
            pingIntent.setClass(TravelPharmacy.this, CountryView.class);
            startActivityForResult(pingIntent, RECEIVE_MESSAGE);
            Log.i("tag for easy filter in logcat 6","I am Working!!!");
            ButtonFromPressed=true;

         }



    }); 
}
```

when getting back the name of the country that be choose in the other activity Override 
onActivityResult and set the name of country in the button

```
     @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

     Button btnCountryfrom = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fromButton);


        CharSequence seq = data.getCharSequenceExtra("response");
        btnCountryfrom.setText(seq);
        ButtonFromPressed=false;



    }
}
```

the onCreate of my second Activity

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.country);

    mListUsers = getCountry();
    lvUsers = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.countrylistView);
    lvUsers.setAdapter(new ListAdapter(this, R.id.countrylistView, mListUsers)); 



    lvUsers.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id)
        {



            Intent pongIntent = new Intent();

            Log.i("tag for easy filter in logcat 1", "information you provide");

            Log.i("tag for easy filter in logcat 2",mListUsers.get(position).pays);

            pongIntent.putExtra("response",mListUsers.get(position).pays);
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,pongIntent);

            finish();
            Log.i("tag for easy filter in logcat 3",mListUsers.get(position).pays);



        }
     });

}
```

The onDestroy() for my second Activity.

```
    @Override
public void onDestroy()
 {

    //     adapter.imageLoader.stopThread();
    //mListUsers=null;


   lv.setAdapter(null);
   super.onDestroy();
 }

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/widget142"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/widget143"
android:layout_height="33px"
android:background="@color/blue"
android:layout_width="fill_parent">
<ImageButton
android:id="@+id/homeImageButton"
android:layout_width="47px"
android:layout_height="34px"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
>
</ImageButton>
<TextView
android:id="@+id/countryTextView"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Country"
android:textSize="20sp"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
>
</TextView>
</RelativeLayout>
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/countrylistView" 
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="250px">
</ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

i will appreciate help!!!

thanks!

Comment: which line throws throws the NullPointer Exception ?

Comment: how can i know (sorry i am new)

Comment: you added already part of stack trace. There you can find in which line you activity crashes

Comment: that is the line that point the null exception public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id)

Comment: does this exception occurs also when you cut everything within onItemClick()?

Comment: can u just paste the whole stack trace? it would be probably easier

Comment: i post the code do you have an idea i understand my onDestroy() its not right but what i should do

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of your previous question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325553/null-exception-in-my-android-program Do not start a new thread for the same question!

Comment: The null pointer is at line 117 of CountryView class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if the ListAdapter exist on R.layout.country where it looks like you are getting the problem:

findViewById(R.id.countrylistView);

Because your listView have not been instatiated. Can you post the country layout

Answer (score 1):

ListAdapter is an interface so you can't new a ListAdapter unless you have created a class named ListAdapter somewhere, that's probably a bad idea and you should use a different name.

When creating an Adapter you pass in a layout for the list item, not the id of the ListView.

Comment: I have done a class ListAdapter

Answer (score 1):

Since you have posted your question in [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5330628/getting-a-nullexception) thread, it is clear that the problem is that `lv` is never initialized in your `activity` before you call `setAdapter` in `onDestroy()`, causing a `NullPointerException` since it is `null`, as it is shown in this snippet of your code:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy()
 {

    //     adapter.imageLoader.stopThread();
    //mListUsers=null;


   lv.setAdapter(null);
   super.onDestroy();
 }
```

Also, when you want to post more data about your problem, just edit your question instead of creating a new one :)
I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be, that

mListUser is null or
mListUsers.get(position) is null?

Comment: what is the problem if mListUser is null?

Comment: the problem is, that you get the null pointer exception. so check it